# Broken text in LaTeX table using tabular

Tags: tables, adjustbox

I have a table in LaTeX using OverLeaf and text inside it is very spaced in some columns, I don't know what's causing this issue and would really appreciate some feedback.

Edit: Also, \adjustwidth and \adjustbox are necessary because I'm using LaTeX form provided by my school which has specific margins, and I want my table to my wider than them

[image]

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.5cm}{0cm}
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.3\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
 & \textbf{Unity} & \textbf{Unreal Engine 4} & \textbf{Godot} & \textbf{CryEngine} \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Cena} & Darmowa dla małych projektów, płatna subskrypcja dla większych & Darmowy do pewnego progu przychodów, potem \% zysków & Darmowy, open-source & Darmowy do pewnego progu przychodów, potem \% zysków \\
 \hline
 \textbf{3D/2D} & Wsparcie dla zarówno 3D jak i 2D & Głównie 3D, choć 2D jest możliwe & Wsparcie dla zarówno 3D jak i 2D & Głównie 3D \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Łatwość użycia} & Relatywnie łatwe dla początkujących & Wymaga więcej nauki niż Unity, ale ma mocne narzędzia & Prosty interfejs, łatwy do nauki & Wymaga więcej nauki, interfejs może być trudniejszy dla początkujących \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Język} & C\# & C$++$, Blueprints (wizualne skrypty) & GDScript (podobne do Pythona), C\#, C$++$ & C$++$, Lua \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Asset store} & Bardzo rozbudowany, dziesiątki tysięcy assetów & Tysiące assetów, mniej rozbudowany niż Unity & Mało rozbudowany, assety tworzone przez społeczność & Mniej rozbudowany, ale zawiera wiele wysokiej jakości assetów \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Wsparcie mobile} & Szerokie wsparcie dla różnych platform mobile & Szerokie wsparcie, ale wymaga więcej konfiguracji niż Unity & Wsparcie dla różnych platform mobile, ale może wymagać więcej konfiguracji & Mniej wsparcia dla platform mobilnych w porównaniu do Unity i Unreal Engine \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Multiplayer} & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera, ale może wymagać więcej pracy & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera, ale może wymagać więcej konfiguracji \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{adjustwidth}
\caption{Porównanie różnych aspektów silników gier komputerowych}
\label{tab:tabelaSilniki}
\end{table}
```

Comment: There are other ways to make a table wider than `\adjust...`, and with a bit more detail we could help you out there.  But wider than your school's specifications is not a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

(updated to incorporate @barbarabeeton's suggestion)

Here's a solution that doesn't use `adjustwidth` or `adjustbox` environments while producing a table whose width is guaranteed *not* to exceed `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{iftex} % for '\ifpdftex' macro
\ifpdftex % pdfLateX is in use
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
\else % either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is in use
   \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi
\usepackage{calc}      % for '\widthof' macro
\usepackage{tabularx}  % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' column type
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\RaggedRight\bfseries}p{\widthof{\textbf{Wsparcie}}}}
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\hyphenation{blue-prints}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} P LLLL @{}}
\toprule
 & \textbf{Unity} & \textbf{Unreal \mbox{Engine 4}} & \textbf{Godot} & \textbf{CryEngine} \\
\midrule
Cena 
  & Darmowa dla małych projektów, płatna subskrypcja dla większych 
  & Darmowy do pewnego progu przychodów, potem \% zysków 
  & Darmowy, open-source 
  & Darmowy do pewnego progu przychodów, potem \% zysków \\
\addlinespace
3D/2D 
  & Wsparcie dla zarówno 3D jak i 2D 
  & Głównie 3D, choć 2D jest możliwe 
  & Wsparcie dla zarówno 3D jak i 2D 
  & Głównie 3D \\
\addlinespace
Łatwość użycia 
  & Relatywnie łatwe dla początkujących 
  & Wymaga więcej nauki niż Unity, ale ma mocne narzędzia 
  & Prosty interfejs, łatwy do nauki 
  & Wymaga więcej nauki, interfejs może być trudniejszy dla początkujących \\
\addlinespace
Język 
  & C\# 
  & C$++$, Blueprints (wizualne skrypty) 
  & GDScript (podobne do Pythona), C\#, C$++$ 
  & C$++$, Lua \\
\addlinespace
Asset store 
  & Bardzo rozbudowany, dziesiątki tysięcy assetów 
  & Tysiące assetów, mniej rozbudowany niż Unity 
  & Mało rozbudowany, assety tworzone przez społeczność 
  & Mniej rozbudowany, ale zawiera wiele wysokiej jakości assetów\\
\addlinespace
Wsparcie mobile 
  & Szerokie wsparcie dla różnych platform mobile 
  & Szerokie wsparcie, ale wymaga więcej konfiguracji niż Unity 
  & Wsparcie dla różnych platform mobile, ale może wymagać więcej konfiguracji 
  & Mniej wsparcia dla platform mobilnych w porównaniu do Unity i Unreal Engine \\
\addlinespace
Multi\-player 
  & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera 
  & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera 
  & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera, ale może wymagać więcej pracy 
  & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera, ale może wymagać więcej konfiguracji \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Porównanie różnych aspektów silników gier komputerowych}
\label{tab:tabelaSilniki}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not mandatory, but the header with "Engine 4" would look much nicer if it were set withine 4}` to prevent the break.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks for this suggestion. I've updated my answer to incorporate it (and to fix a hyphenation issue with the word "blueprints").